# Python: how to speed up this method of exhaustion? Trie?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, tree, trie

I have a corpus with lines of sentences without spaces between words:

```
thenextdayonmayanarchistsstagedarallyatchicagoshaymarketsquare
abombwasthrownbyanunknownpartyneartheconclusionoftherallykillinganofficer
intheensuingpanicpoliceopenedfireonthecrowdandeachother
sevenpoliceofficersandatleastfourworkerswerekilled
```

I need to separate every sentence with vocabulary in a dictionary such as:
`{'the': 1, 'next':2, 'thenext':3'...}`The numbers are just frequencies, which are not important here.

The output will be the variants(lists) of segmentations, just like:
`[[the, next, day...], [thenext, day...]...]`

And here is my code (`filter_worddict` is the dictionary)

```
def segment(sentence):
    if sentence == '':
        yield []
    for w in filter_worddict:
        if sentence.startswith(w):
            for rest in segment(sentence[len(w):]):
                yield [w] + rest

with open('sentences.txt', 'r') as f4, open('result.txt', 'w') as f5:
    for line4 in f4:
        line4 = line4.strip()
        corpus = list(segment(line4))
        for corpusline in corpus:
            f5.write(str(corpusline) + '\n')
```

How can this code speed up? The last time I tried with a corpora (less than 30MB), the dictionary was 5MB, and it took 48h. . .

I have looked around and I've got the choice between Trie and Pytrie, which seems it's a promising solution. But I don't know how to do it in this case correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try to use [threads](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)?